# Dw001 Project in MYProjects but not BLuemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

I am doing the DW001 course and have completed Exercise 5 - Fizzbuzz.  I am now at Exercise 6 which indicates I need to add a service to Exer 5 from the BlueMix catalog.
I can see the Ex5 Project in MyProjects at https://hub.jazz.net/ but cannot see it on the BlueMix dashboard.  Is there a way to migrate Ex5 into BlueMix or is there some config step I have missed?

Regards

Binway

Answer (score 1):

Project might be in another Region at your account. For Exercise 5 , which region did you work ? Could you check US or United Kingdom Region into your dashboard ?

Comment: Yes I am in region US for both envrionments.  And in the options on DevOps(jazz.net) it shows that I have sleected to make this a bluemix project.However, as a result of this I did a bit more investigating and I have two Orgs in Bluemix -  didn't realise this until now - slected the 2nd Org and voila I can see it.

Answer (score 0):

I have two Orgs in my BlueMix under the Account and Support icon where you see Regions there is also Organisations - selecting the 2nd one displayed my exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can see your regions under Account side that is on upper corner at your account.[image]